# Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: error, upgrade

updated today to Version 2.1
On nearly every page I get the error in js console:
Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

```
Therefore nothing is really working:
In the Frontend:
No adding to cart in frontend
In the Backend:
Site all customers showing nothing
Site products/catalog showing nothing
Site products/categories showing nothing

and so on.
```

Does somebody have the same probleme and maybe the solution?

**Forgot to mention:**

```
Error is caused in knockout.js
```

Comment: Same problem over there : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4449
No solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I have noticed that the problem didn't occured in private mode (FF 47.0.1), so I just cleared my whole browser data (cache, session, cookies, etc), then logged in again, and all the grids are working fine...

PS : I can't comment any of the previous messages, hope this time my answer will be accepted as one ?

Comment: yes it works! thx